# Running a full node on a macbook?

Tags: bitcoind, full-node

I'm thinking about running a bitcoind full node to help out the bitcoin network.

Would it be feasible to run a full node through one of the new macbooks?

(12", 250GB HD, 8GB RAM, 1.1 GHz Intel Core M processor)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible. I used to run a full bitcoind node on a 5 year old MacBook Air. I stopped (and moved it to a larger machine) because the size of the blockchain database was becoming annoying - it's [currently 52 GB](https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size) and always gets bigger. If you can spare the space, there's no problem with actually doing it.

Comment: thanks! 52GB is a little big for my hard drive! maybe I'll try on another device though.

Comment: Note that there's a pruning option that would limit your hard disk space usage to whatever you configure. Current pruning is a bit crude (and disables wallet functionatlity!), in the next versions it will be much better.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. The trickiest part is the initial download of the full blockchain. It will take about ~4 days. It might be 52Gb but doing a Get Info will show 64Gb. You've got heaps of space though.

Hopefully you've seen: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#mac-os-x-yosemite-1010x and you'll want to enable incoming connections: https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#enabling-connections

Then you should see yourself on this map here: https://bitnodes.21.co/#join-the-network once you're up and running.